# Removing drip pan on a Frigidaire FFTR1821QS

Tags: appliances, refrigerator

My fridge is giving off a foul odour. Looks like the drip pan is growing mold in it. Looking for advice on how to remove the drip pan so I can clean it. It doesn’t appear to simply slide out from the bottom front of the fridge. It looks like it might come out from the bottom of the fridge but I would have to tip the fridge to attempt removing it this way.

Things I’m wondering are whether there is a better way to remove the pan for this make/model without tipping the fridge, and if I have to tip the fridge is there a specific side this make/model should be tipped on?

I also read that if you need to tip a fridge you should let it stand upright for at least as long as it was on its side before plugging it back in.

Any suggestions would be great! I’ve got a baby in the house and would like to get rid of this issue ASAP.

Make/Model: Frigidaire FFTR1821QS

Comment: To prevent this remember to cover or wrap all food, don't let food fragments get frozen to the condenser.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual for that fridge](http://manuals.frigidaire.com/prodinfo_pdf/Anderson/A04555603en.pdf):

> **Drain pan** *(not removable)* You may hear
>   water dripping into the drain pan during
>   the defrost cycle.

This seems pretty odd to me, but that's what it says.  The toe grill on the front of the fridge does come off to possibly provide a way to see into the drip pan.  I would try to spray or pour (with funnel and tube) some water with a mold cleaner/killer diluted in it.  I would probably try something more gentle than bleach as to not harm the plastic of the tray.

Of course, before any of this, pull out the fridge and make sure it's not something spilled behind the unit or under it.

P.S.  Anything is removable... "not removable" just means it's not going to be easy.  If you're convinced the tray stinks and really needs cleaning, it will come out, but the fridge might need to be on its side.  Possibly not recommended depending on your experience level, but hopefully it doesn't come to that.

Comment: Yeah I’ve already pulled out the fridge and cleaned all around it including underneath and inside. I also pulled off the toe grill at the front and the cover on the back and got a good look inside the pan. Definitely a bit of water and what looks like mold. If I try tipping it do you know if it matters what side? I’ve read that when buying a new fridge and transporting it the box will usually say specifically what side to tip it onto if necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure what side.  The shipping boxes usually say that because of how accessories are placed in the fridge or where padding is in the box, etc. What you do want to do is unplug it first, remove all the shelves and drawers, then tip it over.  Once you're done, set the fridge upright you need to wait before plugging it in.  How long to wait is debatable, but "just as long as it was on its side and then some" is a good rule.  Lubricating oil can move out of the compressor and needs time to settle before running again.

Comment: I'd try to suck out the water with a tube and do the mold remover before trying to unload it and tip it tho.  That's a lot of work.

Comment: Yeah the mold remover is a great idea and I’m going to try that first. One more thing. Is it safe to assume that the water that’s in the drip pan is normal (ie the drip pan is there cause the fridge needs somewhere to drip as it goes through it’s cooling cycles) and that there is nothing mechanically wrong with the fridge and It just happened to grow mold for whatever reason this time?

Comment: There should be air flow behind, around, and under the fridge.  It doesn't "leak" water - it's just condensation out of the air and is normal.  If your cabinets are unusually tight, or the house is unusually humid, it could make the water problem worse.  If the fridge doors don't seal properly, it could make it run more often and produce more moisture.  There's usually not a fan or anything underneath to circulate air, but not totally sure about that.

Comment: There’s a fan by the condenser and there should be enough room around my cupboards and the doors seem to be sealing fine. Maybe I just need to clean the condenser coils since they are quite dirty.

Comment: @Kevin, yep, keep it clean and keep airflow unobstructed.  Sounds like a good plan.

Comment: So it was too awkward to clean the pan while under the fridge. I pulled everything out and tipped it on its side. The pan turned out to be super easy to remove. With just two bolts holding it in place it pulled right out without having to unhook or disassemble or remove any other parts. It was FULL of mold. I had it cleaned and cleaned up the condenser as best as I could with the fridge sideways for only about half an hour so not bad, took just over an hour to complete everything from unplugging the fridge to plugging it back in again. Anyway thanks @JPhi1618

Comment: Nice!  Might still look for some anti-mold stuff to spray in there as a preventative.  Glad it worked out!

Comment: Yep I did spray an anti mold in there so should be good hopefully for a while